# How to measure the energy consumed by my Android app in a certain moment

Tags: java, android, battery, energy, consumption

I have been trying to figure this out since couple months ago because I'm working on my thesis, but unfortunately I have not been able to make it. What I'm doing is a performance analysis regarding energy consumed by an application running an algorithm locally on the phone and the same app but running the algorithm on the cloud and getting the response back to the phone. What I want to do is to try to find an accurate way to obtain the energy consumed by this algorithm since it's executed until it gets the solution (locally and remotely).

Is there any way that I can use in java to do it by using the Android API? I would like to write my own code to get the measures. Please anything you guys think it is helpful PLEASE, let me know...   I appreciate your time and patience,

Alberto.

Comment: Maybe checking out the source of http://powertutor.org/ could help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is such an API available. Here is a link with similar [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960319/how-to-calculate-power-consumption-on-an-android-mobile-that-uses-wifi). If you want because energy/battery consumption depends on may other factors including the efficiency of the compiler.